# A question about the site's terms and condition and experts' viewpoint of a good question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, moderation

I'm definitely going to sound rude to the experts who are actually trying to help solve problems here and I'm really sorry if you feel like I'm being disrespectful but the question is definitely not going to be aimed at you.
I was looking through physics Stack Exchange and this is what I found

[image]

First off id like to say this was in the hot section and has a ton of replies and arguments Without A SINGLE REPLY FROM OP.

A week ago I posted a question in Maths Stack Exchange with a title that explained the question entirely. I couldn't write anything in the question body that could probably have any impact on highlighting my problem and would probably waste everyone's time.

The experts declined to give me any sort of help. Instead proceeded to downvote it (what basically was answered in one single equation by another expert who wanted to help instead of proving that the question violated the Stack Exchange terms) and the question was held off topic and removed because of the downvotes (5-6) but while it was up, one of the experts commented, (I won't mention names but this question might get taken down nonetheless) "Did anyone notice that the question body has nothing written and what's there is absolutely useless and is definitely a bait to get you to answer."

I was totally fine with this because I myself found out that I was violating the site's standards but it wasn't a troll bait. The screenshot above is what actually is troll bait material .

I'm not going to waste your time on telling you people 'how' that question in the screenshot is troll bait material you're all smart enough for that, instead I want to ask this

Why are the experts more focused on finding flaws in your question format and downvoting based on things that don't matter while they should be helping?

My latest question had 5 downvotes for the reason that it was "too broad" while it was just some questions based on a single topic confusion which itself was really simple. When the question body is short the experts downvote it with the reason that it lacks efforts. I had one line doubts and confusions that were denied as "homework questions".

Instead you answer questions like that in the screenshot? It's almost like you visit a question with an intention to downvote it while you actually should be trying to help. Why do I feel like your main objecting before visiting a question is to show other experts how well you know the site's terms instead of helping them?

Comment: This all comes from a fundamental misunderstand of what the SE is and what it is attempting to achieve. Many new users see it as a first stop. It should be your last stop, and you should show your work ("I googled" isn't adequate).  There's also a lot of rules (such as, one question per question) which many folks don't know, many of which appear they actively don't care or can't be bothered to learn. The rules are here to achieve the goals of the site and to favor the experts rather than the askers. If you run off the experts, your site is dead.

Comment: Also, megadupe.

Comment: Google and YT are my first stops, the math question i talked about was actually based on a comment that i saw in another one of my questions (a homework one) . The person who wrote the comment didnt provide explanation for it so i had to make another thread but i had no idea about it. I did tell people that i wasnt trolling and that i dont know anything about the question but they kept at it

Comment: But what good is the site if its experts arnt helping

Comment: Just ignore me, i just felt like asking it. Im thankful for the help i got . But like you said , the site favours expert and maybe its not working for me for that reason. No good questions that i asked were answered and im done is all. You can downvote this question some more till they take it off

Comment: FWIW, the [math.se] question the OP talks about had the title "How is (-3)^sinx not equal to -3^sinx" with the body "That was pretty much the question . that was pretty much the question".

Comment: @ifajra not sure whether you mentioned it to give more credibility to my point or to give the experts something to critique, appreciated either way but that was totally unnecessary as ive already discussed the question in necessary details and even admitted that i noticed how it didnt follow guidelines

Comment: @PizzaThug What good is the site if exerts aren't helping people that can't be bothered to ask quality questions that will actually be useful resources, and instead spend their time answering questions that are appropriate, useful, and will have a lasting value to the internet at large?  Honestly, I feel it's rather self-evidence. Sure, the site might not be any good *to you* if you just want people to do your research for you, or if you're unable to craft a clear or answerable question, but the site *will* be useful to lots of people as a result of focusing its efforts on *quality* questions.

Comment: @Servy i understand but you should see that this is clearly not going in the right direction when experts upvote a question asked by 10 year old "why a law 'works'." Im sure the site it trying to develop itself into some sort of database of "quality" questions for future references to student who might need them. But is this really what it should be doing?

Comment: Speaking of the site's TOC, isn't one supposed to be 13yo or older to use the site? *Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age.*

Comment: @Mike McCaughan that concludes the discussion i guess. Youre a winner

Comment: @PizzaThug I mean, if you don't think that the core mission of the site is a good idea...there are lots of other sites with different core missions.  SO isn't for everyone.  But suggesting that SO should change its core mission and the fundamental values that the whole site is based on to instead focus on helping you specifically is...maybe a touch self centered.

Comment: @Servy neither did i say the site should change its "core mission" nor did i say its a bad idea. I noticed something about you and i must say youre one of those people who create a dull and negative environment in discussions by being the person that keeps on throwing their replies ( baseless in context clearly) without even trying to understand or read what other person is trying to say. You should ask a "quality question" about how to create a healthy environment for discussions . maybe that'll be an advancement towards achieving the site's "core mission". Id now appreciate if you'd be quiet

Comment: @PizzaThug You're saying that the site should be doing things that directly contradict it's core mission, and saying, " is this really what it should be doing?" in response to the site's mission so...yes, I'd say you *are* saying that the site should change its core mission, even if you didn't say so in as many words.  Just because I think that what you're suggesting is a really bad idea, and have explained why, doesn't mean I don't understand it.

Comment: Sorta like how you tried to understand what @Servy was saying?  At the end of the day, SE has a core mission.  One it does rather well.  It doesn't try to do everything for everyone.  It has it's core premise, and it sticks to it.

Comment: Understandable . Have a nice day

Answer (score 5):

> A week ago i posted a question in Maths SE with a title that explained the question entirely. I couldnt write anything in the question body that could probably have any impact on highlighting my problem and would probably waste everyone's time.

You don't waste anyone's time explaining your problem in detail! When I look at a question, I look for details that narrow the scope of the question. Questions in Stack Overflow for example are quite similar. They might have the same *error* but have different code with different causes that create the error. It's those details that are crucial for anyone to properly answer your question. The title is never enough.

---

> The screenshot above is what actually is troll bait material .im not going to waste your time on telling you people 'how' that question in the screenshot is troll bait material youre all smart enough for that,

If you actually read the comments, you would actually know why. A moderator from Physics has this comment:

> [official statement] I'd remind commenters that the OP's account has been deleted (not because of this question, of course), so we shouldn't expect suggestions for improvement or requests for clarification to be responded to, at least not authoritatively. [/official statement] [unofficial statement] In the absence of other information, we can go by the usual definition of "why" in physics, which has to do with showing how this principle arises from a more fundamental model. [/unofficial statement]

Thus the question is deemed on-topic by a moderator and not wrong in any means. True, the question you mentioned could use some editing, but that is not possible without the OP online to know if the edits are appropriate or not (though there has been three edits, one for grammar, another for a definition of the law, and another for a retag).

---

> Why are the experts more focused on finding flaws in your question format and downvoting based on things that dont matter while they should be helping? My latest question had 5 downvotes for the reason that it was "too broad" while it was just some questions based on a single topic confusion which itself was really simple.

Too broad means that the question can have lots of different answers or a really long answer that attempts to answer *all* cases presented within the question. These questions can't be properly answered. In my personal experience, users will view a question first as if being asked that question then decide if it breaks any rules then answer the question if possible.

Users moderate the site (with the help of moderators) and will naturally refuse to answer any question deemed not suitable for the site for basically two reasons: the question and the answer will probably be removed and it deters askers for asking those types of questions because there will be no answers. Nothing wrong here.

---

A moderator from Mathematics comments under your question what your post was:

> FWIW, the Mathematics question the OP talks about had the title "How is (-3)^sinx not equal to -3^sinx" with the body "That was pretty much the question . that was pretty much the question"

To be completely honest to you, I agree that this is a homework question. This can be easily searched up or seen by yourself. There are many ways you could have improved your question, one of them definitely being *adding detail*! Like I said before, I would love to know how is this different from other questions, what approaches did you take in trying to seek the answer to the question, what you are confused about. I clearly cannot speak as I am not a regular nor a user that fully understand the rules of the site but that what I believe what your question lacks.

Your question lacks three key parts that are critical to a make or break here on any site:

- Details on what didn't work on your attempts to figure out the answer (like where are you stuck)
- Details on why you don't understand the equation (or rather, the equation not working)
- Details on what you tried to work out a solution

Just add these three points and you should be fine (don't take my word entirely). You will also need to read the Help Center and maybe ask in chat for some assistance on what's generally on-topic and what's not (if you don't or can't, check in meta for special case questions).

---

Finally, not everyone is an "expert". I'm not an expert on any site I am on. Everyone is just a user with their knowledge limits for lack of a better term. Just because no one answers doesn't mean they don't want to help. It's because they can't help or someone got there first and duplicating an answer is generally not allowed.

Comment: Only thing i couldve written being a biology student is - "they look the same to me" i have limited maths knowledge, and i tried really hard to teach myself it from books,  i didnt go for classes because i have my main subjects to focus on ( i did tell them all this) so i simply tried to learn the subject and was recommended this site by a friend. I get your points though and im grateful for your thorough reply . Thanks a lot

Comment: @PizzaThug If you can't be bothered to submit a question with a question body then that's half your problem.  If you didn't say it in the question body then it didn't happen.  Commentary after the fact doesn't count.  I can't judge the quality of your question based on your comments to it, only the question body, and the quality of your question that says "see title" would be pretty poor.  Question is moot, what you asked about, are actually equal to each other.  If the question wasn't deleted I could prove it.